# Current divergenceless

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, field-theory

We can define a topological current,
\begin{equation}
J_{top}^u = \frac{1}{2v} \epsilon^{\mu \nu} \partial_\nu \phi
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon^{\mu \nu} = − \epsilon^{\nu \mu}$ and $\epsilon^{01} = 1$. The antisymmetry of $\epsilon^{\mu \nu}$ guarantees that this current is divergenceless. Its normalization has been chosen so that the corresponding charge,
\begin{align}
 Q &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} J^0 dx \\
& = \frac{1}{2v} [\phi(\infty)- \phi(-\infty)],
\end{align}

> My question, how do we prove mathematically that  current is
>   divergenceless?

This can be found in  Lewis H. Ryder *Quantum field theory* page no 395

Comment: You just said that it is because of the antisymmetry of $\epsilon^{\mu\nu}$ (which is right)! What have you tried? Where are you stuck? If you tried the obvious thing you would have seen that the hint is well enough.

Comment: Actually I don't understand that how they said current is divergenceless!!!

Comment: The definition of a divergenceless current is $\partial_\mu J^\mu = 0$.

Comment: @MichaelBrown: That should probably be an answer.